# How to implement Google login in Smartface App Studio

Tags: smartface.io

I want to use my app with Google authentication/login. Can any one help me to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the existing setup but with the upcoming setup of Smartface, you will be able to use your own plugins, then you can perform this login.